# Upgrading Liferay 6.2 maven theme into DXP theme

Tags: liferay-7

I want to upgrade a liferay 6.2 theme into liferay DXP theme. Problem is that my existing theme is Maven based. So it shows error when i try to import in theme generators:

I use yo liferay-theme:import and absolute path of my theme, once press enter, it says : "your-theme" doesn't appear to be a theme in the SDK. I want to migrate it to theme generators then upgrade. what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importer is intended to work with the ant-based plugin SDK. You could convert your theme into 6.2 Plugin SDK first, convert it with the tool to the Liferay workspace and then run the update.

This is quite a lot of work and the result will probably be disappointing. You are better off to start from scratch. Generate a new Liferay 7 theme and copy over bits and peases that you would like to reuse. Be careful with the CSS and templates.

Comment: Hi Miroslav,

Thanks for response. Actually converting existing theme into 7 is not a concern for me, I want to upgrade my bootstrap class in css and also upgrade template liferay 6.2 template objects/services to DXP. 

Once i create new theme, upgrade process doesn't work. I just wanted to know that, is there are any way to convert maven theme to dxp theme directly. Instead of making it ant build first then upgrade to dxp theme.

Comment: It seems there is not a direct path.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @MiroslavLigas